# sql query to get last 6 months of data

Tags: sql, db2, sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to get the data for the last 6 months.

This is what I have used:

```
WHERE d_date > DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)
```

and I am getting this error.

```
ERROR: CLI prepare error: SQL0206N  "M" is not valid in the context where it is used
```

also tried

```
WHERE d_date > current date -180
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR: CLI prepare error: SQL0171N  The data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in 
   position "2" of routine "-" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815
```

Please advice.

Comment: The error message clearly shows that the server to which you are passing the query is not SQL Server, as you indicated in the tags, but DB2. You need to refer to the DB2 SQL manual to find out how to work with dates in that product. The `DATEADD()` syntax in your example is SQL Server, not DB2.

Comment: the only reason i added SAS was because I wrote this query in sas enterprise guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Andriy's eagle-eyes, here is (I think) the DB2 syntax:

```
WHERE d_date > current_date - 6 MONTHS
```

And [here is a link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/dateadd?lang=en) to a pretty good function to mirror DATEADD in DB2.

Also, since you mentioned SAS, here is the SAS syntax to do the same thing:

```
WHERE d_date > intnx('MONTH', today(), -6, 'SAME');
```

Although you say you are running this with SAS Enterprise Guide, the syntax you show is not SAS.  The error message you are getting suggests you are submitting "pass-thru" code directly to a database.

Comment: The first part of this answer is best.  Don't mess with creating a DATEADD type function, when the built-in capability will work fine, and can be

Comment: I am running this in SAS Enterprise Guide. WHERE d_date > current_date - 6 MONTHS.... this works. Awesome. Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

In DB2, it should be something like

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(64, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP- d_date AS CHAR(22))) <= 6
```

Remove the SQL-Server tag, that's for MS SQLServer questions.

Comment: got this error:ERROR: CLI prepare error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0171N  The data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in 
       position "2" of routine "-" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: used this and it works
WHERE  d_date BETWEEN
(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS - 1 MONTH)
AND (CURRENT DATE - DAY(CURRENT DATE) DAYS)

Comment: Not only is this solution unnecessarily convoluted, but I wonder if  the query engine would be able to optimize this much.  While the expression @BellevueBob gave is more easily recognized as a deterministic calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
SELECT *
From  PIS.dbo.PIS_tblEmployeeGenInfo
WHERE dtJoiningDate > DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using in code the following:

INSERT INTO Employee(I_EMP, T_CRT, C_SYS, D_HIRED)
        VALUES (21,CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 10,**CURRENT DATE - 6 MONTH**);

This is in DB2, and it is working with no issues.

Hope that will help.

Comment: DB2 SQL reference at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_datearithmetic.html